# C# Read Excel into Data Table - Crashing

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, oledbconnection

Not sure what I am doing wrong, each way I tried has failed. Currently stuck on this code variation... Compiles fine, except when reading the Excel file, my application freezes and then crashes. (Note: I don't care how to do this, I have a very simple task see the bottom of the question if you have better suggestions)

```
   string filePath = string.Empty;
    string fileExt = string.Empty;
    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();                                     //open dialog to choose file
    if (file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)                  //if there is a file chosen by the user
    {
        filePath = file.FileName;                                                   //get the path of the file
        fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);                                      //get the file extension
        if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0 || fileExt.CompareTo(".xlsx") == 0)
        {
            try
            {

                string sSheetName = null;
                string sConnection = null;
                DataTable dtTablesList = default(DataTable);
                OleDbCommand oleExcelCommand = default(OleDbCommand);
                OleDbDataReader oleExcelReader = default(OleDbDataReader);
                OleDbConnection oleExcelConnection = default(OleDbConnection);

                sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + @";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;';";
                oleExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
                oleExcelConnection.Open();

                dtTablesList = oleExcelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

                if (dtTablesList.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    sSheetName = dtTablesList.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                }

                dtTablesList.Clear();
                dtTablesList.Dispose();


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSheetName))
                {
                    oleExcelCommand = oleExcelConnection.CreateCommand();
                    oleExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [" + sSheetName + "]";
                    oleExcelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oleExcelReader = oleExcelCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    int nOutputRow = 0;

                    while (oleExcelReader.Read())
                    {
                    }
                    oleExcelReader.Close();
                }
                oleExcelConnection.Close();
```

My task is really simple. I have to read an excel file (only two columns, infinite rows) and add it to a data table. There are sheet numbers and sheet titles under different categories. Later on, I plan on making an algorithm that will read the data table, and create different dictionaries (for each category) containing sheet numbers and sheet titles.

Here is a sample of an excel file:

[image]

EDIT:

Application crashes without any exceptions I can 'catch', but here are the errors & warnings from Visual Studio debugger:

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaForegroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaForegroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='Common-SavedSelections'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='Common-RuleBasedFilters'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ActiveTabBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaForegroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaForegroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ActiveTabBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaForegroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaForegroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ClientAreaBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=66916835); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=65380607); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=51554558); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=61337839); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=15169645); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=2309080); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=20781721); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=52817761); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Border', AncestorLevel='3''. BindingExpression:Path=ActualHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
The thread 0x3d9c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9358 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8598 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xab5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6aa0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb934 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb1fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8898 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x679c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb04c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3320 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x523c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3a40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x91dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2ccc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8cac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb518 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x70a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x32e4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xad18 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xa8ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x181c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5b64 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8a24 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x971c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3880 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7b68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7e80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x914c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x48f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x858c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb228 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb654 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb8a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7ad0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb628 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x86f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xa128 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xbb38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7ab4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Revit.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[42560] Revit.exe' has exited with code 3221226525 (0xc000041d).
```

Comment: You wrote that it crashes.  Assuming there's an exception thrown, might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  That might help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Your excel sheet should probably be a pure 2D table, with no section headers (like STRUCTURAL)  in between. Just columns with same kind of data in each cell/row.
Also make sure the params HDR and IMEX match your actual content.

Comment: @dbc Edited with errors & warnings I got

Comment: @lidqy thanks for catching the HDR, I changed it to NO. As far as data table, I want to import it as purely 2D. I don't have control over the format of the Excel file I will get. I can easily parse through data myself later. Basically I will do something like this: if column 1 has a value and column 2 does not then it is a header. Anything to follow must have both columns 1 & 2 with values and that will belong to that category, until another condition is reached where column 1 has a value and column 2 does not

Comment: Is this WPF? There doesn't seem to be a WPF tag, yet the error messages similar to what one may see in WPF. Also, the OP doesn't seem to contain any code related to binding.

Comment: @user09938 This is a DLL plugin for Autodesk Revit software which is on a .NET framework. Could you clarify 'binding'?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ExcelDataReader nugget package which made this a walk in the park and with extremely fast results

https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader